# SQL Finding maximum average time for distinct cell

Tags: sql

I have a table with large number of records for which i am trying to find only 10 numbers with the largest average time per number.

So the table may look like so:

```
number  |   time 
012345  |  10s
012345  |  20s
055555  |  50s
055555  |  30s
068976  |  11s
etc...
```

and the output should look like so:

```
number  |  time
012345  |  15s
055555  |  40s
068976  |  11s
```

tried this but to no avail

```
select distinct(destination), avg(totalqueuetime) 
from call 
group by destination, totalqueuetime 
order by totalqueue time desc limit 10;
```

it does not seem to group the numbers.

Comment: remove totalqueuetime  from the group by

Comment: Is it safe to assume that destination is the same as number and time is the same as totalqueuetime?

Comment: @toonice yes. The fields in database are 'destination, totalqueuetime'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code, which has been tested as confirmed as effective.   ...-

(If you wish to sort by average total queue time, as your code sample above suggests)

```
SELECT destination,
       AVG( totalqueuetime ) AS avgTQT
FROM call
GROUP BY destination
ORDER BY avgTQT DESC LIMIT 10;
```

(If you wish to sort by destination, as your desired output sample above suggests)

```
SELECT destination,
       AVG( totalqueuetime ) AS avgTQT
FROM call
GROUP BY destination
ORDER BY destination DESC LIMIT 10;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Note : As for your supplied code, if you remove totalqueuetime from the GROUP BY clause you will not need to use DISTINCT.  Thanks to AVG your SELECT statement will place the average in every returned field, potentially leading to many instances of the same combination of description and average.  Grouping them by Destination will reduce the list to one instance of each combination only.

Comment: I'd rather order by time, however the above results in 10 numbers printed with 'null' times  - the times column is empty in result set

Comment: Are you storing queue time as a number, datetime or something else?

Comment: the queue time is stored as a double

Comment: I've done some research and it looks like double and AVG() don't always get along.  This might be the cause of your problem.  I'll continue researching it until I know more.  Until then, do you use noninteger queue times (such as 4.5 seconds)?

Comment: Well considering the fact that the field is 'double precision' then yes. Time can be either whole int or 4.52 for example.

Comment: Do some of your queue times have a NULL value?

Comment: Yes they do (by the looks of it)

Comment: I see.... it looks like the null values are screwing things up. i corrected it and it seems like its all working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `group by` has two keys.  It should only have one:

```
select destination, avg(totalqueuetime) 
from call 
group by destination 
order by totalqueue time desc
limit 10;
```

Notes on the use of `distinct`.  `select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.  In fact, in almost all cases, you don't need `select distinct` at all -- because you can use `group by`.

In addition, `distinct` is *not* a function.  It applies to the entire entire row.  So, don't use parentheses around the first column, unless you want to confuse yourself.

Comment: The output i get is 10 numbers but they totalqueuetime is empty

Comment: @MaciejCygan . . . Is the data really stored as *numbers*?  Your question specifies that they are, but give the values as `'15s'`.  One doesn't take the average of strings.

Comment: Yes these are numbers (doubles) to be precise. I just included the 's' for visual purposes